# Merge two or more fields before inserting

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to copy data from one table to another. I need to merge the firname and surname into one field called fullname

How can I do that?

```
INSERT INTO table_one (id, full_name, dob)  
SELECT id, first_name, second_name, dob
  FROM table_two
 WHERE id>0;
```

I need to merge the first_name and surname with a comma in the middle

EDIT:

How can i also check if the first name and second name are null before trying to concatinate them. I don't want names like  John,Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out MySQL [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).

After your edit, you will need to use [CONCAT_WS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws). This will skip empty or NULL values.

```
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, second_name) as full_name, dob
```

Comment: I have added an edit to my original question. Can a check for null be added in this example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `CONCAT_WS`.  This will ignore any null values:

```
INSERT INTO table_one (id, full_name, dob)  
SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, second_name) AS name, dob
  FROM table_two
 WHERE id>0;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Answer (score 1):

What you can use here is `CONCAT()` function which  is used to concatenate two strings to form a single strings

So the code would be like

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) as fullname, dob
```

If you want to skip ignore the null values you can use `CONCAT_WS` function